# Jersey: Returns 204 Status Instead of 500

Tags: java, exception, jersey, http-status-codes

I have a Jersey web service with the following a resource class:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/provision")
public class ProvisionResource
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProvisionResource.class);

    @EJB
    private ProvisionService provisionService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("/subscriber")
    public SubscriberAccount querySubscriberAccount(
            @QueryParam("accountNum") String accountNum)
    {
        logger.debug("Entering querySubscriberAccount()");

        final SubscriberAccount account;

        try
        {
            account = provisionService.querySubscriber(accountNum);

            if (account != null)
            {
                logger.debug("Retreived account = " + account);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.debug("No account was found for " + accountNum);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            logger.error("Illegal argument while executing query for subscriber account",
                    ex);

            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.error("Unexpected exception while executing query for subscriber account",
                    ex);

            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

        logger.debug("Exiting querySubscriberAccount()");

        return account;
    }

.... snip ....

}
```

The `provisionService.querySubscriber` throws an exception which is caught by the second catch statement in the `querySubscriberAccount` method (we see the log statement in the file).  However, the client is receiving a `204` status instead of the expected `500` error.

I did find this issue which is similar to mine: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-41 but is quite old and for Jersey 1.3.1.  We are using version 1.9.1.

Has anyone else seen this issue and hopefully figured out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a bug http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1062 for this issue.  Please consider voting for it if you are experiencing the same problem.